# torch: difference in GPU / CPU responses

Tags: torch

I have a simple question. I am trying to understand why is there a large difference in network responses given by the gpu (cuda) and the cpu. Here's a minimal example:

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'
require 'cunn'
require 'paths'

-- a small convnet
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,16, 3,3))
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(16,8, 3,3))
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(8,1, 3,3))

-- randomize weights
local w = net:getParameters()
w:copy(torch.Tensor(w:nElement()):uniform(-1000,1000))

-- random input
x = torch.Tensor(3, 10, 10):uniform(-1,1)

-- network on gpu
net:cuda()
y = net:forward(x:cuda())
print(y)

-- network on cpu
y2 = net:clone():double():forward(x)
print(y2)

-- check difference (typically ~10000)
print("Mean Abs. Diff:")
print(torch.abs(y2-y:double()):sum()/y2:nElement())
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or it's some expected difference between CPU/GPU computation?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, even though the mean absolute difference can be large, the percentage difference is quite small (on the order of 1e-5%):

```
print("Mean Abs. % Diff:")
print(torch.abs(y2-y:double()):cdiv(torch.abs(y2)):sum() / y2:nElement())
```

Is the mean absolute diff. large due to some difference in how cuda handles floating point precision as compared to the cpu?